# Проблема с выводом данных из бд MYSQL через Flask Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Пишу код для вывода данных MySQL через Python и Flask.

```
from flask import flask
import pymysql.cursors
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/news')
def get_news():

connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='news',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM news')
data = cur.fetchall()
return data
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
>          ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block
> ```

Comment: В Python отступы имеют значение.

Comment: А именно что не так?

Comment: Именно - не хватает отступов. Ниже вам дали пример, как должно выглядеть. Рекомендую почитать про отступы в Python, например [тут](https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/basics.html#id20)

Answer (score 1):

Потерял отступы после объявления функции:

```
from flask import flask
import pymysql.cursors
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/news')
def get_news():

    connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='news',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM news')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return data
```

И для работы с базой лучше использовать обертку [Flask-MySQL](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) по скольку после выполнения запроса соеденение будет оставаться открытым и при каждом новом запросе они будут скапливаться и рано или поздно все остановится. А еще лучше использовать [ORM](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/).